# How to center a block element in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with a snippet code. The problem is that the Text "About" is not being displayed in center. I am trying to make a responsive website. Can somebody please take a look and tell me what should i do
this is the link to the animation if somebody is interested.
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/aMmvE

```
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="section-header text-center">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 860 250">
                                <symbol id="web-coderskull">
                                    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="70%" style="text-align: center; ">About</text>
                                </symbol>

                                <g class="webcoderskull">
                                    <use xlink:href="#web-coderskull" class="web-coder-skull"></use>
                                    <use xlink:href="#web-coderskull" class="web-coder-skull"></use>
                                    <use xlink:href="#web-coderskull" class="web-coder-skull"></use>
                                    <use xlink:href="#web-coderskull" class="web-coder-skull"></use>
                                    <use xlink:href="#web-coderskull" class="web-coder-skull"></use>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

th

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem - text is centered, as you can see [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/xLaMwB).

Comment: if you use chrome and open this in inspect element and open this in mobile environment the text goes out of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Add few lines of CSS in your CSS file just copy and paste it

```
.section-header svg{
width:100% 
}
```

if you get the issues let me know